# Given 9 positive numbers taking $N$ distinct values, what is minimum $N$ so that they can be arranged into an invertible square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> - Assume that $(a_1, \dotsc, a_9)$ are different positive numbers. Let    us make a $3\times 3$ matrix $A_S$ by putting them arbitrarily
>     into 9    positions available. Show that there is always a way to
>     assemble them    so that $\det A_S>0$.
> - Assume now that some of the $a_i,\,\,i=1,\dotsc, 9$ are equal and the    total number of different values taken by the $a_i$ is $N\in
>    \{1,    \dotsc,9\}$. What is the minimal $N$ which guarantees the
>     existence    of $A_S$as above with $\det A_S>0$?

There is a solution to the first part [here](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Linear_Algebra%3a_2008_January%3a_Problem_2) which I find satisfactory. In the second part of their solution, they assume incorrectly that if $a,b,c$ are distinct then the matrix $$\left(  \begin{matrix} 
c & c & c \\
c & a & c \\
c & c & b 
\end{matrix} \right)$$ is invertible. (It is not if $ab=c^2$.) Perhaps I could salvage this example, but their strategy is just enumerating cases. Can anyone think of a more conceptual way?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that we do not get to choose the value of those $a_{i}$, but must find an $N$ so that it work for all possible $a_{i}$?

Comment: @Gina That is my interpretation. We don't get to choose the values, nor we get to choose how many $a_i$ take the various values. I.e. given $N=2$ we could be dealing with $3 \,\, a_1$s and $6\,\,a_2$s or $1\,\,a_1$ and $8\,\,a_2$s.

Comment: I don't follow. Why isn't the displayed matrix invertible? Its determinant is $c(c-a)(c-b)$, which is positive when $a,b,c$ are distinct positive numbers.

Comment: @user1551 You're right, of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, I did not read your link, but there is a simple way: pick the first two rows arbitrarily (by picking the first six of your numbers). It is clear that you can rearrange them so that the rows are not multiples of one another (if they are, just swap the third elements of the two rows).  Now, the only way that the third row always gives you zero determinant is if every permutation of the third row lies in the linear subspace spanned by the first two, and so all the permutations are orthogonal to some vector $v_1, v_2, v_3.$
So $v_1 a + v_2 b + v_3 c = 0 = v_1 b + v_2 a + v_3 c.$ Subtracting the left sum from the right, you see that $v_1 = v_2,$ so by symmetry $v_1 = v_2 = v_3,$ so $a + b + c = 0,$ which is impossible since the numbers are positive.

For the second part this method (I think) already gives you $N\leq 5,$ but I should think more.